# How to keep list's element's names with lapply(seq_along())?

Tags: r, lapply

I would like to keep my dataframes' names after each lapply sequence with this code. The resulting list (list2) have all my dataframes names disappeared. How do I improve it? Thank you.

```
list2<-lapply(seq_along(list1), function(i, USE.NAMES=T){
  matrix_a%*%list1[[i]]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `seq_along` to loop over the list,  do it directly.

```
lapply(list1, function(x) matrix_a %*% x)
```

`lapply` uses the name of the object which is passed to it.

Assume your `list1` is something like

```
list1 <- list(x = structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L)), y = structure(c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L)))
```

`list1` has names

```
names(list1)
#[1] "x" "y"
```

but `seq_along(list1)` has no names.

```
names(seq_along(list1))
#NULL
```

Hence, no names are present in the final output of `lapply`.

---

If for some reason you have to pass the index you can add the names later

```
setNames(lapply(seq_along(list1), function(i) matrix_a%*%list1[[i]]), names(list1))
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the key cause of my code's complication.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` as well

```
Map(`%*%`, list(matrix_a), list1)
```